# neither UseSignalR or UseEndpoints can be found when trying to setup SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm trying to setup signalR in my asp.net core 2.2 solution.

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-5.0) guide, and have gotten to the step of adding this configure method in my startup file, in the configure function:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
});
```

The issue is though, that my app object as no `ùseendpints`.
After [searching a bit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/5.0/signalr-usesignalr-useconnections-removed), I can see that something called `UseSignalR` used to be used instead of `ùseendpints`:

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<SomeHub>("/path");
});
```

However there isnt anything for `UseSignalR` either.

The only that I can find which sounds usefull, is something called `UseMiddleWare`.

I then try replicating the steps that I should take from the documentation:

```
        app.UseMiddleware(endpoint =>
        {
            endpoint.MapHub
        });
```

But this doesnt work at all. The endpoint has no field called ``MapHub`.

I have no idea what to do, why can't I just follow the documentation?

My entire startup file looks like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Seges.SC.Feature.Personalization.Services;
using Seges.SC.Foundation.ApplicationInitialization.Initialization;

namespace Seges.SC.Feature.Personalization.Initialization
{
    [SuppressMessage(
        "UnusedCode",
        "CA1812:Never instantiated",
        Justification = "Instantiated through reflection/dependency injection")]
    [SuppressMessage(
        "ReSharper",
        "UnusedMember.Global",
        Justification = "Instantiated through reflection/dependency injection")]
    internal class PersonalizationInitializer : BaseApplicationInitializer
    {
        public override string Name => nameof(PersonalizationInitializer);

        public override void RegisterDependencies(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<ICurrentUserService, CurrentUserService>();
            services.AddSignalRCore();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {

            app.UseMiddleware(endpoint =>
            {
                endpoint.MapHub
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `BaseApplicationInitializer`? Is the `Configure` method even being called here? This doesn't look like a normal startup class.

Comment: yes, it's from a helix project with a slitghtly alternative setup.

Comment: No idea what Helix is, but perhaps that is what is interfering?

Comment: Can you at least provide a "Helix" documentation? I bet nobody even knows what that is, including me

Comment: Or at least start with a basic ASP.NET Core app, get it working in there and then try to migrate it into this Helix thing.

Comment: Helix is a pattern where a project with vs is made up of a bunch of smakker projects https://helix.sitecore.com/. It's usually used in conjunction with the sitecore cms, and probably a lot less common than my initial impression

Comment: Well documentation leads to the examples on github. And you can find there, that even projects designed with this pattern have a `Startup` class where you can do all you configuration. Link: https://github.com/Sitecore/Helix.Examples/tree/master/examples/helix-basic-aspnetcore/src/Project/BasicCompany/rendering